# parsing nested arrays to populate uitableview in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, decodable

This is the API response which I have parsed

```
{
"status": 0,
"message": "Friends found.",
"friends": [
    {
        "id": 52,
        "meetings": [
            {
                "id": 47,
                "meeting_with": "Bbb"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The model class

```
struct TotalMeetings: Decodable {
var status: Int
var message: String
var friends: [FriendDetail]?
}
struct FriendDetail: Decodable {
var id: Int
var meetings: [MeetingsDetail]
}
struct MeetingsDetail: Decodable {
var id: Int
var meeting_with: String
}
```

Im calling the API here and the call is successful.

```
var meetingssData :Friends!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do{
   meetingsData = try decoder.decode(TotalMeetings.self, from: response.data!)
    let meet = [self.meetingsData!.friends].compactMap({$0}).flatMap({$0})
        print(meetingsData!) 
}catch{
    print(error)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FriendsMeetingTVC
    
    return cell
}
```

**Please guide me how do I populate the tableview with the response coming from API call.**

Comment: I know how to create a tableview Im asking for how do I pass that data into tableview, which approach will be used?

Comment: It's not even clear what you want to display. A table view data source requires at least a data source array.

Comment: Your `meetingsData` needs to be an instance variable rather than local so that `cellForRowAt` can use the array of `FriendDetail`.  (Assuming you want to show friends in your table.)

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to declared array instance of type according to your need either FriendDetail or MeetingsDetail.
2. After fetching data from api parse it and store mapped data into an array instance. Then, reload table view.
3. **numberOfRowsInSection** method of tableview returns number of rows using your array count.
4. You can access value by using dot notation as shown in **"cellForRowAt indexPath:"** method.

   ```
   class MeetingVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource {
    var friendsArr = [FriendDetail]()

    func fetchFriendDetail() {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let meetingsData = try decoder.decode(TotalMeetings.self, from: response.data!)
        self.friendsArr = meetingsData.friends ?? []//[meetingsData.friends].compactMap({$0}).flatMap({$0})
        print(self.friendsArr) 
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsArr.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FriendsMeetingTVC
    cell.emailTxt.text = friendsArr[indexPath.row].email
    return cell
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: hey that's very helpful and working. Please one question how do I access the values of [MeetingsDetail]

Comment: Same as email:-  friendArr[indexPath.row].meetings.

Comment: let meetingId = friendsArr[indexPath.row].meetings[indexPath.row].id im trying this wat but it shows an error index out of range